# ClearCase : list the content of a directory (ls) using CAL

Tags: com, list, automation, directory, clearcase

In ClearCase, you can list the content of a directory using "cleartool ls".

My question is how can I do the same thing using CAL (ClearCase Automation Layer). The reason I prefer the COM API is because I won't have to parse the output of "ls".

So far, I am able to get the VOB and the View successfully, but I didn't find any method for listing the content.

My code so far:

```
IClearCase cc = new ApplicationClass();
CCVOB vob = cc.get_VOB("\\VOB-name");
CCView view = cc.get_View("ViewTag");
```

Thank you for your help.

I wrote VonC's answer in C# for those interrested.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("View path here", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    try
    {
            CCVersion ver = cc.get_Version(file);
            Console.WriteLine(ver.Path);
    }
    catch(Exception) {/*the file is not versioned*/}
}
```

Comment: Completed my answer for the "rmname" part.

Comment: Completed my comments about your "ICCElement" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is a good start:

```
Set CC = Wscript.CreateObject("ClearCase.Application") 
Set DirVer = CC.Version(".") 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(DirVer.Path) 
Wscript.Echo "Files under source control: " 
For Each File in Folder.Files 
     On Error Resume Next 
     Set Ver = CC.Version(File.Name) 
     If Err.Number = 0 Then 
           Wscript.Echo Ver.ExtendedPath 
     End If 
Next
```

The idea being to use `ICCVersion` methods to try accessing the version of a file. If it does not return an error, it is indeed a versioned file.

---

> Now I know the file is versioned, how can I remove it (rmname).

**Do not use RemoveVersion()**:
Removes irretrievably the version (equivalent to `cleartool rmver`)
WARNING! This is a potentially destructive operation. Because CAL does not prompt the user for input under any circumstances, there is no confirmation step when `RemoveVersion` is invoked. Invoking `RemoveVersion` is equivalent to running `cleartool rmver` with the `-force` option.

Instead use the **`RemoveName` from the `ICCElement` interface**.

Comment: CC.Version(".") will only work if you set the current directory to the view path (through Environement.CurrentDirectory in C#). If it's the case, can't jou just remove the second line, and do "Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("-- your view path here --")" ?
In other word, the second line is necessary?
Ty.

Comment: In the case you mention, this second line would be unnecessary indeed. But I have not fully tested yet.

Comment: Ok, ty again. If I dare to add another little question. Now I know the file is versioned, how can I remove it (rmname). There is RemoveVersion(...), but I am not sure it's the equivalent of rmname.

Comment: Warning: there are two "remove version" in ClearCase: rmver is the most dangerous one since it remove *definitively* the version from the VOB. Rmname just dereferences the version from the list of files referenced by its parent directory.

Comment: Use RemoveName from the ICCElement interface instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So, basicaly, using ICCElement, we can also check if a file is versioned? I've just tried it, and it throws a "Not a VOB object" if the item is not versioned.

Comment: Correct. Simply ICCElement gives other services about a versioned file: services common for any version (whereas ICCVersion gives access to the current visible version of the element)